# Issue Parsing JSON Data in Python because of Random Value

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm scraping a website for product reviews.  I can successfully get the JSON data, but I'm having an issue with the parsing.  The levels of data are like this:
payload -> reviews -> 22Y6N61W6TO2 -> customerReviews.

The data I want is in the "customerReviews level.  However, the "6IYETQATGRMP" value will be different when looking at another item.

I don't want to have to use a different python script for each item to account for this one value.  How do I use something like a wild card or something to get the data I'm after?

I'm using Python 3, requests, and JSON in my script.

My script looks like this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data['payload']['reviews']['22Y6N61W6TO2']['customerReviews'])
    print(df)
```

Below is a section of the JSON I'm working with:

```
"payload": {
      "products": {},
      "offers": {},
      "idmlMap": {},
      "reviews": {
         "22Y6N61W6TO2": {
            "averageOverallRating": 4.4783,
            "roundedAverageOverallRating": 4.5,
            "overallRatingRange": 5.0,
            "totalReviewCount": 759,
            "recommendedPercentage": 89,
            "ratingValueOneCount": 35,
            "ratingValueTwoCount": 27,
            "ratingValueThreeCount": 30,
            "ratingValueFourCount": 115,
            "ratingValueFiveCount": 552,
            "percentageOneCount": 4,
            "percentageTwoCount": 3,
            "percentageThreeCount": 3,
            "percentageFourCount": 15,
            "percentageFiveCount": 72,
            "activeSort": "relevancy",
            "pagination": {
               "total": 759,
               "pages": [
                  {
                     "num": 1,
                     "gap": false,
                     "active": true,
                     "url": "sort=relevancy&page=1"
                  },
                  {
                     "num": 2,
                     "gap": false,
                     "active": false,
                     "url": "sort=relevancy&page=2"
                  },
                  {
                     "num": 3,
                     "gap": false,
                     "active": false,
                     "url": "sort=relevancy&page=3"
                  },
                  {
                     "num": 4,
                     "gap": false,
                     "active": false,
                     "url": "sort=relevancy&page=4"
                  },
                  {
                     "num": 5,
                     "gap": false,
                     "active": false,
                     "url": "sort=relevancy&page=5"
                  },
                  {
                     "num": 6,
                     "gap": false,
                     "active": false,
                     "url": "sort=relevancy&page=6"
                  },
                  {
                     "num": 0,
                     "gap": true,
                     "active": false
                  },
                  {
                     "num": 38,
                     "gap": false,
                     "active": false,
                     "url": "sort=relevancy&page=38"
                  }
               ],
               "next": {
                  "num": 0,
                  "gap": false,
                  "active": false,
                  "url": "sort=relevancy&page=2"
               },
               "currentSpan": "1-20"
            },
            "customerReviews": [
               {
                  "reviewId": "248695872",
                  "authorId": "13b0b650b7694a54267279bf80e0fdfa99cc7c3c5150d32aff7db274e74c07f5f6e7f7b6c4fe8cb64a007c9e3c0f0c04",
                  "negativeFeedback": 0,
                  "positiveFeedback": 0,
                  "rating": 5.0,
                  "reviewTitle": "Amazing",
                  "reviewText": "This thing is amazing. I cooked bbq ribs in 30 mins. Then caramelized for 6 mins in my oven. They was awesome. Best kitchen appliance of 2020. Wish i had bought it before dec 31st. Buy one folks. You'll love it.",
                  "reviewSubmissionTime": "1/1/2021",
                  "userNickname": "Keith",
                  "badges": [
                     {
                        "badgeType": "Custom",
                        "id": "VerifiedPurchaser",
                        "contentType": "REVIEW"
                     }
                  ],
                  "userAttributes": {},
                  "photos": [
                     {
                        "Id": "e917ed53-cf49-48af-b454-42f3fd87536a",
                        "Sizes": {
                           "normal": {
                              "Id": "normal",
                              "Url": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/dfw/6e29e393-988c/k2-_d716ba9d-2c5b-4f82-b9a6-588575975fe6.v1.bin"
                           },
                           "thumbnail": {
                              "Id": "thumbnail",
                              "Url": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/dfw/6e29e393-988c/k2-_d716ba9d-2c5b-4f82-b9a6-588575975fe6.v1.bin?odnWidth=150&odnHeight=150&odnBg=ffffff"
                           }
                        },
                        "SizesOrder": [
                           "normal",
                           "thumbnail"
                        ]
                     }
                  ],
                  "videos": [],
                  "externalSource": "bazaarvoice"
               }
```

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]

Comment: and include sample of JSON response that you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe that you can get the key first like this

```py
key = list(data["payload"]['reviews'].keys())[0]
df = pd.json_normalize(data['payload']['reviews'][key]['customerReviews'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a simple variable to have a standard export function.

```py
    import json
    import random

    id_1 = '6IYETQATGRMP'
    id_2 = '7GAADHOOLWCT'
    id_3 = '8WWBHOLWQNNZ'
```

```json
    the_json_data = '''{
        "level_1": {
            "level_2": {
                "6IYETQATGRMP": {
                    "level_4": "your_1st_level_4_data"
                },
                "7GAADHOOLWCT": {
                    "level_4": "your_2nd_level_4_data"
                },
                "8WWBHOLWQNNZ": {
                    "level_4": "your_3rd_level_4_data"
                }
            }
        }
    }'''
```

```py
    your_var = random.choice([id_1, id_2, id_3])
    data = json.loads(the_json_data)
    print(data['level_1']['level_2'][your_var]['level_4'])
```

In this way you can use 'your_var' to set the desired ID and the function will work as expected if the ID exists.